# TypeScript - async await not wait until funtion fully executed?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I need to fetch data from the API after getting the username, password and title from storage. Hence I use async await thrice before finally calling the API.

The data can be fetched correctly, but somehow the refresh timeout function completed first before     the getData function fully executed.

```
doRefresh(event) {
        setTimeout(async () => {
          await this.storage.get('username').then(async username => {
            await this.storage.get('password').then(async password => {
              await this.storage.get('title').then(async tempName => {
                await this.myService.getJSON(username, password, tempName, "keywordA", this.section).then(async ()=> {
                  await this.myService.getJSON(username, password, tempName, "keywordB", "trainingInfo");   }).finally(async ()=> {
                    await this.getData();
                    console.log('done');
                    event.target.complete();
                });
              })
            })
          });   
          
        }, 2500);
        
      }
```

Have tried to remove async await, and put the code like this, but still not working as expected. Seems like console.log / event.target.complete always execute first before waiting getData function complete.

```
doRefresh(event) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.storage.get('username').then(username => {
            this.storage.get('password').then(password => {
              this.storage.get('title').then(tempName => {
                this.myService.getJSON(username, password, tempName, "keywordA", this.section).then(()=> {
                  this.myService.getJSON(username, password, tempName, "keywordB", "trainingInfo");   }).finally(()=> {
                    this.getData();
                    console.log('done');                    
                });
              })
            })
          });   
        event.target.complete();
        }, 2500);

      }
```

Comment: If I were you I would erase this nesting nightmare from earth. Start over and use RxJS instead

Comment: @Osakr Agree on the RxJS, but even without RxJS this logic can be properly written in JavaScript without seven levels of nesting.

Comment: The thing is that Angular relies heavily on RxJS, implementing promises in an Angular app is never a good idea. This can be rewritten to be better in pure JS, but as long as the app increases size this will become worse and worse. The thing is to do the right thing from the beginning

Comment: What does `this.getData()` do? Looks like it doesn't return a promise, or the promise fulfils before you want it to. Please post its code, we cannot help you without.

Comment: @Osakr Okey noted on that, will try to study and implement the code using RxJS instead. Sorry as I'm quite new to the Angular and JS, hence it explained why the code is poorly written.

Comment: @qwerty no need to apologize ^^

Comment: @qwerty you really don't need to learn RxJS as well to solve this issue.  I'd personally suggest practicing with promises before adding a whole new stack and paradigm on top.

Comment: btw I just wanna say thanks to everyone, finally the code's working. I take the suggestion from @Osakr to implement RxJS and using Promises. It works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you're mixing await and .then, best to use one or the other.
Here's it re-written with async/await, it's much more readable in my opinion.

```
async () => {
try {
  const username = await this.storage.get('username')
  const password = await this.storage.get('password')
  const tempName = await this.storage.get('title')
  await this.myService.getJSON(username, password, tempName, "keywordA", this.section)
  await this.myService.getJSON(username, password, tempName, "keywordB", "trainingInfo")
  await this.getData();
  console.log('done');
  event.target.complete();
 } catch (e) {
  console.log("something went wrong")
 } 
}
```

Comment: Totally agree, but if the OPs code is not working for them, neither will this. The actual problem is within `getData`.